# c++ question:After assigning value to a variable,the other variable changed

Tags: c++, pointers

Following codes are my own API for index prior queue.When I test insert function,I get wrong answer.Then I debug codes,I found that the value of array *qp* changed after executing sentence----`item[k]=v`which is in insert function.Why the value of array *qp* changed after assigning value to array *item*?

```
template <class T>
class IndexPriorQueue{
private:
    int index;//the num of items
    int size;//capacity
    int* pq;//index binaryheap
    int* qp;//qp[pq[i]]=pq[qp[i]]=i
    T* item;//item array;
public:
    IndexPriorQueue(int qsize){//constructor function
        size=qsize;
        index=0;
        pq=new int(size+1);
        qp=new int(size+1);
        item=new T(size+1);
        for(int i=0;i<size+1;i++)
            qp[i]=-1;

    }
    void insert(int k,T v){
        if(contain(k)){
            cout<<"index is already in queue"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        //cout<<"insert"<<endl;
        item[k]=v;//debug,after excuting this sentence,the value of qp exchanged??
        pq[++index]=k;
        qp[k]=index;
        swim(index);
    }
    bool contain(int k){
        return qp[k]!=-1?1:0;
    }
    void swim(int j){
        while(j>1){
            if(item[pq[j/2]]<item[pq[j]]){
                exch(j/2,j);
                j=j/2;
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    void exch(int m,int n){
        int temp=pq[m];
        pq[m]=pq[n];
        pq[n]=temp;
        qp[pq[m]]=m;
        qp[pq[n]]=n;
    }
    void display(){
        cout<<"item:";
        for(int i=1;i<size+1;i++){
            cout<<item[i]<<"  ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"pq:";
        for(int i=1;i<size+1;i++){
            cout<<pq[i]<<"  ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"qp:";
        for(int i=1;i<size+1;i++){
            cout<<qp[i]<<"  ";
        }
        cout<<endl;

    }
};
```

Following codes are main function

```
int main(){
    cout<<"before insert:"<<endl;
    IndexPriorQueue<char> ipq(10);
    ipq.display();
    ipq.insert(1,'a');
    cout<<"after insert:"<<endl;
    ipq.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problems is your allocations. Take for example

```
new T(size+1)
```

That allocates ***one*** object of type `T` and initializes it to the value `size + 1` (i.e. it calls the `T` constructor with `size + 1`).

If you need to allocate an "array" you should use *square* brackets `[]` as in

```
new T[size+1]
```

That will allocate an array of `size + 1` number of `T` objects.

A much better solution though, is to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of doing it all manually yourself.

Comment: Thanks!You really helped me!I made a low_level mistake,I need to study how to allocate memory,I will try to use std::vector.